# "Temporary file write failure" when trying to change primary key in MySQL

Tags: mysql, primary-key, errors

In MySQL, When I trying to change primary key by this query:

```
 ALTER TABLE `resources` DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD
 PRIMARY KEY (`role_id`, `category_id`, `lang`, `model`, `rule`);
```

I execute this query with MySQL root user, but this error occurred:

> `#1878 - Temporary file write failure.`

My table design is:

```
CREATE TABLE `resources` (
    `role_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
    `category_id` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 ,
    `lang` BINARY(2) NOT NULL ,
    `model` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
    `rule` CHAR(4) NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`, `lang`, `model`, `rule`, `role_id`)
 )
 ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

This table have about 2000 rows.

I use MySQL 5.6

Why this error has occurred?

what should I do?

Comment: You need to be more specific than that. Are you changing values in a primary key, altering the column(s) used by the key, changing to a different candidate key, ...?  Also how large is the target table? *You should add to your question the current design of the table and its indexes/keys, the current size of the table, and the SQL you ran to make the change*. Changing a column's properties on a large table might involve spooling a lot of data to disk so it could simply be a space issue.

Comment: @DavidSpillett or maybe a access issue (mysql user not having access to temp dir?)

Comment: @DavidSpillett I edited my question as you said.

Comment: @ypercube I execute the query by root privilege.

Comment: @ypercube I mean mysql root user, I use debian 7 wheezy, yes /tmp has enough space, MySQL correctly doing all other read/writes, so the system user (that mysql runs as) has write access to temp directories.

Comment: What does `SELECT @@tmpdir;` show? (just to confirm that this is not an issue - and start looking elsewhere.)

Comment: @ypercube it returns `/tmp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, I did the following:

```
create table resources_with_key like resources;
alter table resources_with_key add primary key(`category_id`, `lang`, `model`, `rule`, `role_id`);
insert into resources_with_key select * from resources;
```